# The first DFS path using a itertaive DFS rather than a recursive one

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search, path-finding, undirected-graph

I am trying to implement a simple Dfs path finding for a problem in which I have to print the very first path I encountered and nothing if no path is found.
I was able to do it with Recursion but i am having trouble with the iterative version.

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void PrintDFSpath(int **a, int *visited, int start, int end, int v)
{
    map<int, int> parentMap;
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(start);

    while (!s.empty())
    {
        int currEle = s.top();
        visited[currEle]=1;
        s.pop();
        if (currEle == end)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (int i = v - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (a[currEle][i] == 1 && !visited[i] && i != currEle)
            {
                if( !parentMap.count(i) )
                    parentMap[i] = currEle;
                s.push(i);
                visited[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        if (s.empty())
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    int i = end;
    cout<<end<<" ";
    while (i != start)
    {
        cout<<parentMap[i]<<" ";
        i = parentMap[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int v, e;
    cin >> v >> e;
    int **a = new int *[v];

    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[v];
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++)
            a[i][j] = 0;
    }
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        cin >> x >> y;
        a[x][y] = 1;
        a[y][x] = 1;
    }

    int v1, v2;
    cin >> v1 >> v2;

    int *visited = new int[v];
    for (int j = 0; j < v; j++)
        visited[j] = 0;

    PrintDFSpath(a, visited, v1, v2, v);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using an adjacency matrix here.

I have already implemented some of the things that I found on StackOverflow
such as the map

Also, the get the same path as that in recursive order I am inserting the children into the stack in rev order.

Here is the **Problem statement**

> Given an undirected graph G(V, E) and two vertices v1 and v2(as integers),
> find and print the path from v1 to v2 (if exists).
> Print nothing if there is no path between v1 and v2.
> Find the path using DFS and print the first path that you encountered.
>
> V is the number of vertices present in graph G and vertices are numbered from 0 to V-1.
> E is the number of edges present in graph G.
>
> Print the path in reverse order. That is, print v2 first, then intermediate vertices and v1 at last.

**Input schema** :

> Line 1: Two Integers V and E (separated by space)
> Next E lines: Two integers a and b, denoting that there exists an edge between vertex a and vertex b (separated by space)
> Line (E+2): Two integers v1 and v2 (separated by space)

I am thinking the issue is coming from the following statement.

```
if (currEle == end)
{
    break;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to go about correcting it. Plz suggest something

The test case :
7 8
0 1
1 2
4 5
6 5
1 6
1 2
2 3
0 3
0 3

output : 3 2 1 0

Comment: If you have some input which causes the incorrect output, then it's easy to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values to see when things start to go wrong.

Comment: You really should be using `std::vector`:  This `int **a = new int *[v];`-- Replace this with `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(v, std::vector<int>(v));`.  Not only does that take care of the memory leak, it also initializes all of the items to 0.  The same thing here: `int *visited = new int[v];` could be `std::vector<bool> visited(v);`

Comment: Also, if you have the test case already, put the data directly in the code.  There is no need for `cin` or any input statements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie will do the vector changes I was just trying to use minimum STL and I forgot the delete statements but definitely vector is the best to solve this. Also this the test case that failed there are many test cases which is why I cant hardcode it.

Comment: @ASHUTOSHSINGH -- If that is a test case that fails, put that case in the code.  All you need is just one failing case.  In other words, set `v` and `e` directly, set the position in the vector to the 1, etc.  Then not only is it easier for other s to simply take your code, compile it, and run it, you now can fix without having to type in the data over and over again.

Comment: ...also, people here can reproduce it. In other words, you have the required [mcve]. However, use a debugger to step through the code, it's an important skill to learn and you might as well do that now. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you get a code that solves your testcase example, by removing the following code lines from your inner `for` loop:

```
if( !parentMap.count(i) )
```

and

```
visited[i] = 1;
```

In your code, the `parentMap` registers the first occurrence of a path from the currently processed element to its children. In order to mimic the recursive DFS behavior, `parentMap` should register the path from the current element to its parent. By overriding an existing map element when you encounter a new path that was not yet visited, you get the desired data.

The `visited` collection should contain the elements that you already **processed**. If you add children to `visited` within the inner `for` loop, you mark them as processed, when they are only **enqueued** for processing at some point in the future. Operating on a collection that doesn't fulfil its contract is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, man this solved my doubts and i was able to make various other changes to the code as.